# Geocoding using Excel spreadsheet

Tags: qgis, geocoding, excel

Can I add a spreadsheet with addresses to QGIS and then geocode it?

Comment: it depends how well your addresses are formatted.

Answer (score 2):

You cant directly convert the excelsheet .For that first save the Excel sheet as .CSV file and Use Add Delimiter Text Layer Plugin to convert the Text Layer Plugin to point Shape file .Then
go to Fetch Plugins option there you will find Geocoding Plugin which can do Geocoding and Reverse Geoding process using Google web Services.I think this might help your question.

Comment: Does that 'geocoding' plugin support geocoding from  CSV, or would you suggest the MMQGIS plugin?